# Best document format for actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a clean and efficient way to import documents in a flash presentation?

I have a big number of doc documents to import in a flash presentation and i'm wondering what's the best way to attach them. I've worked passing them to HTML before, but the doc to HTML conversion is messy, ugly and doesn't output valid HTML code, besides, it's a chore to clean the embed CSS style the conversion leaves inside the code.

So, is there a library that allow to use a more portable format? if not, is there a clean way to convert a doc file to valid html code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FlashPaper to print the doc to a FlashPaper swf which is basically like a document with built-in Flash based viewer.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/

> FlashPaper 2 allows anyone to convert printable files into Macromedia Flash documents or PDF files with one click.